# UIPickerView - black bar on the right when many components

Tags: iphone, objective-c, formatting, uipickerview

I have to create a UIPickerView with 14-16 components. Everything initializes and works great, however, I get a weird black bar on the right (see image) that wastes already tight space.

Is there a way to get rid of it? Is there also a way to get rid of all black spacing between the components and gray lines inside the components?

Thank you.

[image]

```
(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:     
(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [label setText:[numArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return label;
}
```

Comment: There has to be a better design for what you're trying to do if you're using a picker with 14-16 columns. The users finger could be bigger than and one of those columns, and that's sure to get annoying fast. Perhaps you should use a text field with a keypad instead. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do this for...

Comment: The screen grab is from portrait view, but the app is actually designed to run in landscape, which provides ample space for any size finger. UIPickerView is the most suitable component for the functionality that is required.

Comment: I don't think that the default pickerview is designed to work with so many columns. If you want such extreme functionality you probably have to make your own.

Comment: It functions great and exactly as the client needs, just need to get rid of that black bar on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the width of your picker views? How did you set the width?
Is width fixed or did you use something like
(landscape mode in mind)
`CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame) // use this as width in landscape mode`

Then you would divide that width with number of picker views (14-16).
With that width of picker views you shouldnt have that black bar.

If you did do what i just wrote already, and i guess you did, 
then that may be status bar space if you created all that programatically (as you have).
When creating ui components outside storyboards, some components position themselves at 0.0f, 20.0f for status bar. Some of them are UINavigationController.